# javascript - avoid repetable code

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, dry

I have a page with a button that calls a menu modal. The modal contains two more buttons that call two submenus - one for each button. Watch the pen:
https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/yoxJGO

It actually works. But the current problem is that I re-write a repeatable code to call each submenu:

```
$('.show-submenu-1').on('click', function () {
  $('.submenu-1.offcanvas').addClass('offcanvas--active');
})

$('.show-submenu-2').on('click', function () {
  $('.submenu-2.offcanvas').addClass('offcanvas--active');
})
```

This approach seems to be pretty dumb. I need a solution with less repetition, something like forEach function for arrays:

```
var menus = [
  '.show-submenu-1',
  '.show-submenu-2'
];

menus.forEach(function(menu){
  $(menu).on('click', function () {
    $(`${menu}.offcanvas`).addClass('offcanvas--active');
  })
});
```

Of course, this scenario won't work. How can I make my code DRY?

Comment: I just took a glance at the codepen, so I may be missing something, but could you not use the same CSS class for submenu 1 and submenu 2? They appear to be styled identically, and that would save you from repeating yourself, I think. Maybe just submenu as a class?

Comment: Can't you just remove `.show-` from the array items and add it to the selector doing the binding? `$(\`.show-${menu}\`).on()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I hope I got the question right but you could use data-attributes for something like this. Just set a general class for .show-submenu and mark their connection to the menus with a number in a data-submenu=x attribute. Where x would be the number in .submenu-x.
And then you do something like this:
Notice that i changed .show-submenu-1 to .show-submenu. Make sure every trigger has this class. Also add a data-submenu=x for every submenu you want to use.

```
$('.show-submenu').on('click', function () {
  var number = $(this).attr("data-submenu");
  var selector = '.submenu-' + number + '.offcanvas'
  $(selector).addClass('offcanvas--active');
})
```

So the data-submenu is used to pair the trigger and the modal. This way you can stick to an easy to read html code and a short bit of jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Use markup:

```
<div class="submenu" data-index="1">
<div class="submenu" data-index="2">

<button class="show-submenu-button" data-submenu-index="1">
<button class="show-submenu-button" data-submenu-index="2">
```

Then:

```
$('.show-submenu-button').on('click', function () {
    var index = $(this).attr('data-submenu-index');
    $('.submenu[data-index="' + index + '"]').addClass('offcanvas--active');
})
```

There is little value to using classnames that are so specific that they identify every element on the page individually.  Classnames should define a *class* of elements that behave the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var menus = [1, 2];

menus.forEach(index => {
  $(`.show-submenu-${index}`).on('click', () => {
    $(`.submenu-${index}.offcanvas`).addClass('offcanvas--active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is interesting, but I've never seen this syntax. Does it tell to bring in the menu items (in this case 1 & 2) to the foreach in the var index and then fill in the ${index} with the current index value? Is there a special library or framework required for this (other than jquery of course)?

Comment: This feature name is _template strings_, javascript supports it natively, starting from ES6 [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I had a look at template literals and they seem really useful, thank you for the elaboration :)

Comment: Glad that my answer was helpful for you. Check [this github repo](https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features) there are described most of ES6 features.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this as well.

```
$('.show-submenu-1, .show-submenu-2').on('click', function (event) {
$(event.target).hasClass('show-submenu-1'){
   $('.submenu-1.offcanvas').addClass('offcanvas--active');
}else{
  $('.submenu-2.offcanvas').addClass('offcanvas--active');
} 
})
```

it would be better to have your show-submenu-1(as showmenu) and submenu-1(as submenu) in same parent element that allows you to use `closest()` method and make life easy

for eg:

```
$('.show-submenu').on('click', function (event) {
    $(event.target).closest('.submenu').addClass('offcanvas--active');
    })
```

Comment: This will cause clicking submenu 2 to affect submenu 1